# DataGridView Adding Button Columns after Setting DataSource

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I set the DataSource of a DataGridView to a DataTable. I then added 2 button columns to the DataGridView. The DataGridView looks fine on the form, however,when I insert the buttons at indexes 1 and 6 the DataGridView returns their click events as index 0 and 1. This seems to happen by adding buttons apart from the DataSource.

Any recommendations on how to solve this problem?

```
DataTable dataTable= someMethod();

DataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

// Add a button to the DataGridView at the specified position
DataGridViewButtonColumn btnEdit = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
btnEdit.Name = "btnEdit";
btnEdit.Text = "Edit";
btnEdit.HeaderText = "Edit Quantity";
btnEdit.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
DataGridView.Columns.Insert(1, btnEdit);

DataGridViewButtonColumn btnDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
btnDelete.Name = "btnDelete";
btnDelete.Text = "Delete";
btnDelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
btnDelete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
DataGridView.Columns.Insert(6, btnDelete);
```

Comment: How you confirm that only column index 0 and 1 return click event?

Comment: Instead of checking the index, you should be checking the name of the column, so .Columns(index) becomes .Columns("btnDelete")